# Java Shallow Copy

Tags: java

```
public class Rectangle implements Cloneable {
    double width;
    double height;
    Date dateCreated;

@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}

public Rectangle(double width, double height, Date dateCreated){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}
public double getArea(){
    return width * height;
}

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
 }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(2,1, new Date());
       Rectangle rectangle1 = null;
    try {
        rectangle1 = (Rectangle) rectangle.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rectangle.setDateCreated(new Date(1));
    System.out.println(rectangle1.getDateCreated());
    System.out.println(rectangle.getDateCreated());
    }
 }
```

In the code above, since clone() method creates shallow copy, I expect that non-primitive types have the same reference. So, why changing the content of dateCreated field in the object rectangle do not change the same field in rectangle1 field?

Comment: "*changing the content of dateCreated field*" is changing the reference

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `clone` method doesn't do anything. You need to implement it.
2. Even if your `clone` method was implemented, you would still run into the issue you describe in your question. You aren't changing the value of the `Date` object, you are replacing it with a new `Date` object. That has no effect on the original `Date` object, which is still referenced by `rectangle1`.

Comment: if(rectangle.getDateCreated() == rectangle1.getDateCreated()){
            System.out.println("True");
        } //this does not return true. According to your answer, I think this should return true.

Comment: That's because your `clone` method doesn't do anything. But even if it did, you would still run into the problem you are describing in your question.